# Reverse proxy varnish using subpath in docker

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am following the tutorial [production-postgis-vector-tiles-caching](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/production-postgis-vector-tiles-caching). However when I try to setup pg_tileserve to serve tiles under reverse proxy and varnish also under reverse proxy, I always get an error `Error 503 Backend fetch failed`. My docker-compose looks like

```
tiles:
 image: pramsey/pg_tileserv
 volumes:
   - ./config/pg_tileserv.toml:/etc/pg_tileserv.toml
 environment:
   - DATABASE_URL=postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASS}@${POSTGRES_HOST}/${POSTGRES_DB}
   - TS_URLBASE=${VECTOR_TILES_URL}
   - TS_BASEPATH=/tiles
depends_on:
  db:
    condition: service_healthy
restart: always

cache:
 image: eeacms/varnish
 environment:
   BACKENDS: 'tiles:7800'
   DNS_ENABLED: 'false'
   COOKIES: 'true'
   PARAM_VALUE: '-p default_ttl=600'
   VARNISH_BACKEND_PATH: '/'
depends_on:
  tiles:
    condition: service_started
restart: always

nginx:
 image: nginx
 volumes:
   - ./sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro  
 depends_on:
   - tiles
   - cache 
 ports:
   - "80:80"
```

And my nginx config looks like this:

```
location /tiles {
    proxy_pass http://tiles;
    
}

location /cache {
    proxy_pass http://cache;
    
}
```

How can I modify my varnish config, considering my tiles are available on http://localhost/tiles and varnish should be available from http://localhost/cache

Answer (score 0):

As far as 503 errors go, you can use `varnishlog` to debug. Please run the following command in your Varnish container to figure out what's going on:

```
docker exec -ti -u0 cache varnishlog -g request -q "RespStatus == 503"
```

Please attach the relevant log output to your question.

However, your `docker-compose.yml` seems to expose some inconsistencies: your `tiles` server does a `32772:7800` portforwarding. Meaning local port `32772` is being forwarded to host port `7800`.

The `BACKENDS` environment variable of your `cache` container still refers to local port `7800` on the `tiles` container.

Either your change the local port of your `tiles` server back to `7800` as done in the [tutorial](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/production-postgis-vector-tiles-caching). Or if for some reason, port `32772` is the right one, alter your `BACKENDS` configuration and point it to port `32772`.

*Please also consider using the [official Varnish Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/varnish). It is supported by the community and by Varnish software.*

Comment: I edited the compose file, the port forwarding for the tiles is not needed as I am exposing through nginx